# NSString Assignment & Retaining

Tags: cocoa, nsstring, constants, retain

Just a simple question on NSStrings, I have a piece of code that assigns a value to a string, depending on what is found it is either assigned a value by substringToIndex or the constant string @"0.00", is it okay to use

```
// Save if value found, otherwise set to 0.00
if (parsedCharacters == nil || [parsedCharacters isEqualToString:@""])
        self.currentDiscountedPrice = @"0.00";
else
{
  // Truncate extra digits from string to 2 decimal places (find full stop, save 2 places after it)
  NSRange fullStopRange = [parsedCharacters rangeOfString:@"."];
  self.currentDiscountedPrice = [parsedCharacters substringToIndex:(fullStopRange.location + 3)];
}
```

for the assignment since it will release the old value & retain the new value?

There is no way of knowing whether the var was assigned the constant string or the substringToIndex returned value in the previous iteration but I was told calling retain & release on constant strings is harmless, is this true?

Comment: What I'm basically asking is, in the above code should I rather explicitly release the old value & retain the substringToIndex value or it okay to just use self.currentDiscountedPrice = for both assignments?

Comment: OT: instead of `parsedCharacters == nil || [parsedCharacters isEqualToString:@""]`, I’d write `parsedCharacters.length == 0`. Because of Objective-C’s message-to-nil semantics, this will detect `nil`, it’s likely to be marginally faster for non-nil, and of course is simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSString is not special; all Cocoa objects follow [the Cocoa memory-management rules](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/). As long as you do, too, you'll be fine.

> I was told calling retain & release on constant strings is harmless, is this true?

Yes. You should treat them the same as any other string you don't own: Retain it if you want to own it, or make a copy and own that; then be sure to release what you own.

> … should I rather explicitly release the old value & retain the `substringToIndex` value or it okay to just use `self.currentDiscountedPrice =` for both assignments?

You should use the property everywhere but in `init` methods and `dealloc`. Those are the only methods that should explicitly send `retain` and `release` messages to the object in the instance variable.

The reason for both sides of that paragraph is that you, or a subclass, may implement custom accessors for the property. The custom behavior may be dangerous to have run on a half-inited or half-deallocked object, but you'll probably want it everywhere else.

There is no harm in passing a constant-string object to a property setter. It will retain or copy the object as normal.

On that note, when a property's value is an object of a class with a mutable variant (as NSString has NSMutableString), you should declare the property as copying its value (`@property(copy)` or `@property(nonatomic, copy)`), in order that you do not take co-ownership of someone else's mutable object. If they mutate the object, this could cause problems for you, particularly if you stored the object in a hashing collection (such as as a dictionary key) rather than in an instance variable.